# How to reproduce google sheets LEFT function using apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 40 different cells of data in row 2 of spreadsheet.  All the data starts with a 2 letter code and then a space and then some other information.  I want to be able to pull the first two letters of the string and put it in the row directly above that. What code could I use to achieve that?

Comment: Type in google: "JavaScript string method" and you'll find everything you need...

Comment: see for instance : .substring() example of http://learnjs.io/blog/2014/01/28/js-string-method-examples/

Answer (score -1):

```
 function usingFunction(){
 var sheetName         = 'Sheet1';  //change according to your need 
 var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var selectedSheet     = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName); 
 var mySheet           = selectedSheet;
 var lastRow           = mySheet.getLastRow();
 var N                 = lastRow;

for (var i=2;i<=N;i++){// taking i=2 for headers change accordingly

var left           ='LEFT($A'+i+',2)'; //Change "$A"according to your cell reference and "2" by the characters you need

mySheet.getRange(i, 2, 1, 1).setFormula(left);//sets formulas 

//pasting it as values keep if needed

var getB =mySheet.getRange(i, 2, 1, 1);
var valueB  ="B"+i;
getB.copyTo(mySheet.getRange(valueB), {contentsOnly:true});
}}
```